# Build dotnet core application within docker - runs forever

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a simple `dotnet core` application and wrap it inside a docker image. During the build of the image, all `dotnet` commands (like `dotnet restore` or `dotnet build`) run forever without making any progress, but occupying the CPU around 50%. I let it ran for at least an hour but it never stops. A normal `dotnet restore` takes just a few milliseconds, so there is definitely something off.

Steps to reproduce.

1. Install dotnet sdk.

   - `dotnet --version`
   - Gives: 3.1.200
2. `mkdir TestApplication`
3. `cd TestApplication`
4. `dotnet new console`
5. `dotnet run/restore/build` all work fine
6. Next, we create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

WORKDIR /

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .

RUN dotnet build
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
COPY --from=build /aspnetapp/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

7. `docker build -t myTestApplication .`

Result: Always hangs at the first `dotnet` command, even if playing around. Running on macOS Catalina (10.15.6).

Anyone any idea what is going wrong here? I tried creating an image for a Python application which works fine, so it seems to be related to `dotnet`.

**Edit 1:**
Adding the verbose log output:

```
(base) ➜  TestApplication docker build -t testerico .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/9 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
 ---> 9ab567a29502
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ec8404eb93c3
Step 3/9 : COPY *.csproj ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 86a4e6875b03
Step 4/9 : RUN dotnet restore --verbosity diagnostic
 ---> Running in 1791f6205c36
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/MSBuild.dll -nologo -distributedlogger:Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/dotnet.dll*Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/dotnet.dll -maxcpucount -target:Restore -verbosity:m -verbosity:diagnostic ./TestApplication.csproj
Build started 08/29/2020 11:49:23.
Environment at start of build:
NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE = skip
DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER = true
PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER = true
HOME = /root
DOTNET_HOST_PATH = /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL = PSDocker-DotnetCoreSDK-Debian-10
MSBuildExtensionsPath = /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/
MSBuildSDKsPath = /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks
HOSTNAME = 1791f6205c36
PWD = /
DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_SESSIONID = af7fc2b0-1308-4572-99e7-30bae6e369e8
MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly = true

11:49:23.778     0>Process = "/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet"
                   MSBuild executable path = "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/MSBuild.dll"
                   Command line arguments = "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -nologo -target:Restore -verbosity:diagnostic -distributedlogger:Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/dotnet.dll*Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/dotnet.dll"
                   Current directory = "/"
                   MSBuild version = "16.7.0-preview-20360-03+188921e2f"
                   Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'...
                   Property reassignment: $(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)="/obj/" (previous value: "obj\") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Current/Microsoft.Common.props (56,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage)=";PackTool;_PackProjectToolValidation" (previous value: ";PackTool") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.PackProjectTool.props (15,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(OutputType)="Exe" (previous value: "Library") at /TestApplication.csproj (4,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(PublishProfileImported)="false" (previous value: "true") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportPublishProfile.targets (28,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**" (previous value: ";bin/Debug//**") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (171,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(IntermediateOutputPath)="obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\" (previous value: "obj\Debug\") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (185,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(OutputPath)="bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/" (previous value: "bin/Debug/") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (186,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_FrameworkVersionForImplicitDefine)="3_1" (previous value: "3.1") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets (165,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_DebugSymbolsProduced)="true" (previous value: "false") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (149,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_DocumentationFileProduced)="false" (previous value: "true") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (158,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(ProcessorArchitecture)="msil" (previous value: "") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (487,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DelaySign)="" (previous value: "false") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (527,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)="Auto" (previous value: "") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (3491,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)="Off" (previous value: "Auto") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (3492,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(MSBuildAllProjects)=";/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/NuGet.targets;/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Current/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportAfter/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ImportAfter.targets" (previous value: ";/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/NuGet.targets") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Current/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportAfter/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ImportAfter.targets (16,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(ProjectAssetsFile)="/obj/project.assets.json" (previous value: "/obj//project.assets.json") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets (24,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(ProjectAssetsCacheFile)="/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/TestApplication.assets.cache" (previous value: "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TestApplication.assets.cache") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets (29,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(ResolveAssemblyReferencesDependsOn)="
                         
                         ResolveProjectReferences;
                         FindInvalidProjectReferences;
                         GetFrameworkPaths;
                         GetReferenceAssemblyPaths;
                         PrepareForBuild;
                         ResolveSDKReferences;
                         ExpandSDKReferences;
                       ;
                         ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild;
                         _HandlePackageFileConflicts;
                       " (previous value: "
                         ResolveProjectReferences;
                         FindInvalidProjectReferences;
                         GetFrameworkPaths;
                         GetReferenceAssemblyPaths;
                         PrepareForBuild;
                         ResolveSDKReferences;
                         ExpandSDKReferences;
                       ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets (71,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(PrepareResourcesDependsOn)="
                         ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild;
                         _HandlePackageFileConflicts;
                         
                         ;
                         PrepareResourceNames;
                         ResGen;
                         CompileLicxFiles
                       
                       " (previous value: "
                         ;
                         PrepareResourceNames;
                         ResGen;
                         CompileLicxFiles
                       ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets (77,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**" (previous value: ";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (27,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**" (previous value: ";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (29,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**;**/*.user" (previous value: ";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (32,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj" (previous value: ";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**;**/*.user") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (33,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj;**/*.sln" (previous value: ";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (34,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj;**/*.sln;**/*.vssscc" (previous value: ";bin/Debug//**;obj\Debug\/**;bin//**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj;**/*.sln") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (35,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(ResolveAssemblyReferencesDependsOn)="
                         
                         
                         ResolveProjectReferences;
                         FindInvalidProjectReferences;
                         GetFrameworkPaths;
                         GetReferenceAssemblyPaths;
                         PrepareForBuild;
                         ResolveSDKReferences;
                         ExpandSDKReferences;
                       ;
                         ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild;
                         _HandlePackageFileConflicts;
                       ;
                         ResolveTargetingPackAssets;
                       " (previous value: "
                         
                         ResolveProjectReferences;
                         FindInvalidProjectReferences;
                         GetFrameworkPaths;
                         GetReferenceAssemblyPaths;
                         PrepareForBuild;
                         ResolveSDKReferences;
                         ExpandSDKReferences;
                       ;
                         ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild;
                         _HandlePackageFileConflicts;
                       ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets (14,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_GenerateRuntimeConfigurationPropertyInputsCache)="/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/TestApplication.genruntimeconfig.cache" (previous value: "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TestApplication.genruntimeconfig.cache") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (53,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_DefaultUserProfileRuntimeStorePath)="/root/.dotnet/store" (previous value: "/root") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (97,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(CoreBuildDependsOn)="
                         _CheckForBuildWithNoBuild;
                         
                         BuildOnlySettings;
                         PrepareForBuild;
                         PreBuildEvent;
                         ResolveReferences;
                         PrepareResources;
                         ResolveKeySource;
                         Compile;
                         ExportWindowsMDFile;
                         UnmanagedUnregistration;
                         GenerateSerializationAssemblies;
                         CreateSatelliteAssemblies;
                         GenerateManifests;
                         GetTargetPath;
                         PrepareForRun;
                         UnmanagedRegistration;
                         IncrementalClean;
                         PostBuildEvent
                       ;
                         GenerateBuildDependencyFile;
                         GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles
                       " (previous value: "
                         BuildOnlySettings;
                         PrepareForBuild;
                         PreBuildEvent;
                         ResolveReferences;
                         PrepareResources;
                         ResolveKeySource;
                         Compile;
                         ExportWindowsMDFile;
                         UnmanagedUnregistration;
                         GenerateSerializationAssemblies;
                         CreateSatelliteAssemblies;
                         GenerateManifests;
                         GetTargetPath;
                         PrepareForRun;
                         UnmanagedRegistration;
                         IncrementalClean;
                         PostBuildEvent
                       ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (118,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(CoreCleanDependsOn)="
                         _SdkBeforeClean;
                         
                       " (previous value: "") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (127,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(RebuildDependsOn)="
                         _SdkBeforeRebuild;
                         
                         BeforeRebuild;
                         Clean;
                         Build;
                         AfterRebuild;
                       
                       " (previous value: "
                         BeforeRebuild;
                         Clean;
                         Build;
                         AfterRebuild;
                       ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (134,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(CompileDependsOn)="
                         
                         ResolveReferences;
                         ResolveKeySource;
                         SetWin32ManifestProperties;
                         FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;
                         _GenerateCompileInputs;
                         BeforeCompile;
                         _TimeStampBeforeCompile;
                         _GenerateCompileDependencyCache;
                         CoreCompile;
                         _TimeStampAfterCompile;
                         AfterCompile;
                       ;
                         _CreateAppHost;
                         _CreateComHost;
                         _GetIjwHostPaths;
                       " (previous value: "
                         ResolveReferences;
                         ResolveKeySource;
                         SetWin32ManifestProperties;
                         FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;
                         _GenerateCompileInputs;
                         BeforeCompile;
                         _TimeStampBeforeCompile;
                         _GenerateCompileDependencyCache;
                         CoreCompile;
                         _TimeStampAfterCompile;
                         AfterCompile;
                       ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (396,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(CreateSatelliteAssembliesDependsOn)="
                         
                         _GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs;
                         ComputeIntermediateSatelliteAssemblies;
                         GenerateSatelliteAssemblies
                       ;
                         CoreGenerateSatelliteAssemblies
                       " (previous value: "
                         _GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs;
                         ComputeIntermediateSatelliteAssemblies;
                         GenerateSatelliteAssemblies
                       ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (758,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DesignerRuntimeImplementationProjectOutputGroupDependsOn)="
                         
                         ;
                         
                         ;
                         BuildOnlySettings;
                         PrepareForBuild;
                         AssignTargetPaths;
                         ResolveReferences
                       
                       ;
                         _GenerateDesignerDepsFile;
                         _GenerateDesignerRuntimeConfigFile;
                         _GatherDesignerShadowCopyFiles;
                       " (previous value: "
                         ;
                         
                         ;
                         BuildOnlySettings;
                         PrepareForBuild;
                         AssignTargetPaths;
                         ResolveReferences
                       
                       ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.DesignerSupport.targets (21,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_ShimInputCacheFile)="/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/TestApplication.shiminput.cache" (previous value: "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TestApplication.shiminput.cache") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.PackTool.targets (94,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(_ShimCreatedSentinelFile)="/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/TestApplication.shimcreated.sentinel" (previous value: "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TestApplication.shimcreated.sentinel") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.PackTool.targets (96,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefineConstants)="TRACE;DEBUG" (previous value: "TRACE") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.CSharp.targets (31,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(DefineConstants)="TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP;NETCOREAPP3_1" (previous value: "TRACE;DEBUG") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.CSharp.targets (34,5)
                   Resolving SDK 'ILLink.Tasks'...
                   Property reassignment: $(MSBuildAllProjects)=";/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/NuGet.targets;/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Current/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportAfter/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ImportAfter.targets;/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets" (previous value: ";/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/NuGet.targets;/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Current/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportAfter/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ImportAfter.targets") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets (18,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(PackageDescription)="Package Description" (previous value: "") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets (32,5)
                   Property reassignment: $(GenerateNuspecDependsOn)="Build;_LoadPackInputItems; _GetTargetFrameworksOutput; _WalkEachTargetPerFramework; _GetPackageFiles; " (previous value: "_LoadPackInputItems; _GetTargetFrameworksOutput; _WalkEachTargetPerFramework; _GetPackageFiles; ") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets (55,5)
```

Comment: Your docker file deviates from this one: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

Comment: It does but that should not cause any issues regarding the stuck `dotnet restore` command. It would also be fine if it simply fails or something, but the process just continues running forever without any output.

Comment: Can you add verbosity to you command? Like `dotnet restore --verbosity diagnostic`

Comment: Added it to my question above, good hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think the issue was missing `WORKDIR /app` directive, I added it and
> now it is working. So weird...

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1825

Hence, changing `WORKDIR /` to `WORKDIR /app` should solve the issue.

Docker file from doc for Core 3.1: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

A typical Docker file generated by VS looks like below, and uses Core Debian images (which I'm also using when deploying to OpenShift/Kubernetes). In example below, my application is named "WebApplication".

```
    #See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["WebApplication.csproj", ""]
    RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/."
    RUN dotnet build "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"]
```

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I am back, might be a few hours. Thanks! If that is the case and a sub folder is the recommended way, I wonder why `dotnet new console` does not follow that best practice.

Comment: Yeah lol, that was actually the issue. But first, WHY is this an issue and second, WHY does it work outside of docker? So weird indeed... Thanks for helping!